# Backstack not showing the result wanted

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have 3 fragments namely frag1, frag2, frag3.

The first fragment has two buttons. The first button click places frag2 on the screen and the click on second button places frag3 on the screen.

The work flow the first button should follow is

frag1 -> frag2

frag2 -> frag3

When back button is pressed:  frag3 -> frag1

The work flow the second button should follow is

frag1-> frag3

When the back button is pressed: frag3 -> frag1

The work flow is fine but when I perform the first button operation (i.e frag1->frag2->frag3->frag1) and then the second button operation the fragment frag1 is replaced by frag3 but when I press the back button I still get frag3 on the screen and then pressing the back button again the application closes.

Can anyone please help me on what wrong approach I am taking to this problem and please give the solution to it. It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for your problem is

- In you activity's layout file make an  FrameLayout and put fragment1 with visibility = visible.
- When fragment 2/3 is to be shown just change visibility of frag1 to gone and add frag 2/3 to the framelayout and change visibility of frag1 to gone
- When you are in frag2/3 and have to move to frag3/2 remove 2/3 and add 3/2
- When you are in frag2/3 and want to go back to 1 remove frag2/3 and show frag1